# Jenkins DSL API for copyartifact permissions

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to add a call to my jenkins job dsl that will configure the job to give permission to another build to copy artifacts. However, I am unable to find a command for it in the Jenkins Job DSL API: 
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/

Here is the option I am trying to set using the DSL:[image]

Does this command exist? Is there anyways to setup my groovy to do this if it doesnt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in DSL to set that permission, but you can use the [Dynamic DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL). 
The Job DSL API viewer can be opened at http://localhost:8080/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html where `localhost` is your Jenkins host. Search for `copyArtifactPermission` as an example:

```
job('example') {
  properties {
    copyArtifactPermissionProperty {
      projectNames('one, two')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

is it this [one](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.copyArtifacts)?

```
job('example') {
    steps {
        copyArtifacts('upstream') {
            includePatterns('*.xml', '*.properties')
            excludePatterns('test.xml', 'test.properties')
            targetDirectory('files')
            flatten()
            optional()
            buildSelector {
                latestSuccessful(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT
It seems this may have been fixed in the [google group for job-dsl](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/job-dsl-plugin/bZmFRv49FF4)

```
configure { project ->
  project / 'properties' / 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifactPermissionProperty' / 'projectNameList' {
    'string' "*-foo"
  }
}
```

I think they may have changed the interface though and you need to provide explicit job names now, but I haven't got the plugin so I can't check

Comment: This is the one to actually copy the artifacts. I am trying to give permission to a job so that it can copy the artifacts.